# Capture Data in Windows CMD terminal

Tags: python, windows, cmd

Hi Everyone i wants to capture all my personal system's traffic before it enters to default Gateway. I want's to decrypt my traffic in a specific format then pass it to gateways .m not sure is it possible ?? if yes then how ???

i tried using different commands somehow it show captured data but unable to modify and send it to gateway

Comment: looks like you want to re-invent VPN?

Comment: actually i alredy routing my traffic to my custom gateway(Configured my own OpenVPN ) now i wants an extra layer on it ..... my goal is to Encrypt all traffic by my own ENC/DEC library and then pass it to VPN tunnel..... on other side decryption part is alredy tested ....